# Why does React require so many node_modules? How can I limit loading all those files to make it worth using React?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

When I `npm install react` I get the following folders in node_modules:

- amdefine
- asap
- base62
- core-js
- envify
- esprima-fb
- fbjs
- js-tokens
- jstransform
- loose-envify
- promise
- react
- source-map
- through
- ua-parser-js
- whatwg-fetch

I have worked with React before in personal projects but I have never delved too deep into what actually happens (how many files actually get downloaded) when I run npm install "something". I always figured it was just magic.

My company doesn't use any node modules (Our stack is PHP). How can I make the argument that including all the above react dependencies are worth it? (I really just want more experience using React). How can I limit the number of dependencies for React? What are the fewest number of dependencies I need to run React?

p.s. `npm install react` downloads 1350 files!

Let me know what you think!

Comment: I'm being silly. I can delete all of those other folders. All I think I need is react.min.js

Comment: Yes, just grab a pre compiled/bundled version that is intended for browser-only work. You shouldn't need the `npm` version unless you're doing JavaScript on the server or trying to do your own complex JS bundling.

Answer (score 0):

The question is - why would you want to limit the number of those modules?

If some of your backend is written in node - don't worry, it's okay.

If your entire backend is written in PHP and you just want to use react on the client side, why don't you use `bower` to install it?

Also you should check the final size of your minified, compressed, and gzipped javascript - you may be surprised how small it is even with all those dependencies.